# $\omega$-string avoiding a set of substrings

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

Given a set of strings $S$ over $\{a,b\}$. How to determine whether there is an infinite sequence consisting of ${a, b}$ (i.e., a $\omega$-string), which doesn't have any string in $S$ as a substring?

The total length of all substrings in $S$ is at most $20000$.

Comment: Are you looking for an efficient algorithm, or for any algorithm?

Comment: In general, I am looking for an efficient algorithm, but if you have any ideas on any algorithm, it may have been useful for me.

Comment: Construct a DFA for the language of all *finite* strings not containing any of the given strings as a substring. Check whether there is a reachable state which belongs to a cycle containing only accepting states. This algorithm runs in exponential time.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?  What's the context in which you encountered it?

Answer (score 1):

If every $\omega$-string contains a substring in $S$, then we say that $S$ is *unavoidable* or a *universal hitting set (UHS)*. There is a classical algorithm for detecting whether a set of substrings is unavoidable, described for example in Lothaire's *Algebraic combinatorics on words*, Section 1.6.

Construct a graph $G$ as follows. The vertices are all prefixes of strings in $S$. For every prefix $p$ and symbol $\sigma$, we connect $p$ to the longest suffix of $p\sigma$ appearing in the graph. The set $S$ is unavoidable iff every cycle in $G$ passes through a vertex corresponding to a word in $S$.

To see this, suppose first that every cycle in $G$ passes through a vertex corresponding to a word in $S$. Consider some $\omega$-word $w$. Starting at the vertex $\epsilon$, "read" the symbols of $w$ one by one. Eventually you will hit a cycle (since $G$ is finite). By assumption, this cycle contains a vertex $v$ in $S$, and so $w$ contains $v$. In the other direction, tracing an $S$-less cycle (replacing each edge by the symbol $\sigma$ used to create it) results in a periodic $\omega$-word which avoids $S$.